# Rails nested form reject if

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

Hello i have nested form (address table in user registration)
And user can disable or enable the nested form (via checkbox which trigger javascript which is disabling all textboxes)

In model i want reject disabled form.
So how i can do that ? I though about some each function and if all textboxes are blank the form is disabled, if 1 and more textbox is entered it will go through normal validation.. or what is good solution of this ?

```
//accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:city].blank? }
```

Comment: do it in the controller!

Comment: Hello phoet, why ? I have it in Class User and it works good, with .blank? method, but i need check all textbox values if they are blank not just only city.

Comment: Use nested-form gem for this. https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: but that is not what im looking for, i dont want let user add zilions addresses and remove them.. i only need do some each cycle on array and if one or more information is filled lets do validation or if its enabled.. im not so good for playing with gems.. im happy i have working javascript :-)